# Sample database schema + domain model for trying out an ORM

Tags: language-agnostic, orm, domain-driven-design

Is there a (freely available) sample of a DDD domain model with an accompanying schema that makes use of several ORM features (inheritance, value types, etc) that could be used to test an ORM?

It's easy to create a simple Order/OrderItem schema, but that never prepares you for the intricacies down the road.

(I'm coming at this from a .NET slant, though the question is largely platform agnostic)

Comment: I'm not sure if this meets your criteria, but it may be worth a look: http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Michael - it's definitely a good start. Add it as an answer; I'll vote you up now and mark it as the answer if it suits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Chinook Database:

chinookdatabase.codeplex.com